# Returning a polymorphic class

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

i'm creating a little xbox application and for the beginning it should detect what game is currently running and then bypass and/or launch a program. Since i recently learned polymorphism i thought i could implement it here to gain efficiency. Below is my code (not as efficient as i thought it would be):

```
DWORD(__cdecl *XamGetCurrentTitleID)() = (DWORD(__cdecl *)())ResolveFunction("xam.xex", 0x1CF); // Resolves current Game ID

typedef enum _XBOX_GAMES : DWORD // Enum that holds Game IDs
{
    BOOT_UP = 0x00000000,
    DASHBOARD = 0xFFFE07D1,
    FREESTYLEDASH = 0xF5D20000,
    COD_WORLD_AT_WAR = 0x4156081C,
    COD_MODERN_WARFARE = 0x415607E6,
    COD_MODERN_WARFARE_2 = 0x41560817,
    COD_BLACK_OPS_1 = 0x41560855,
    COD_MODERN_WARFARE_3 = 0x415608CB,
    COD_BLACK_OPS_2 = 0x415608C3,
    COD_GHOSTS = 0x415608fC,
    COD_ADVANCED_WARFARE = 0x41560914,
    COD_BLACK_OPS_3 = 0x4156091D,
    DESTINY = 0x415608F8,
    GTAV = 0x545408A7
} XBOX_GAMES;

DWORD GameChecker()
{
    DWORD lastID = NULL;

    Game *game;
    AW aw; BO1 bo1; BO2 bo2; BO3 bo3; Ghosts ghosts; MW2 mw2; MW3 mw3; Dashboard dashboard;

    for (;;)
    {
        if (XamGetCurrentTitleID() != lastID)
        {
            switch (XamGetCurrentTitleID())
            {
                case BOOT_UP:
                    // nothing
                    break;
                case DASHBOARD:
                    game = &dashboard;
                    game->Launch();
                    break;
                case COD_MODERN_WARFARE_2:
                    game = &mw2;
                    game->Launch();
                    break;
                case COD_MODERN_WARFARE_3:
                    game = &mw3;
                    game->Launch();
                    break;
                case COD_GHOSTS:
                    game = &ghosts;
                    game->Bypass();
                    game->Launch();
                    break;
                case COD_BLACK_OPS_1:
                    game = &bo1;
                    game->Launch();
                    break;
                case COD_BLACK_OPS_2:
                    game = &bo2;
                    game->Bypass();
                    break;
                case COD_BLACK_OPS_3:
                    game = &bo3;
                    game->Bypass();
                    break;
                case COD_ADVANCED_WARFARE:
                    game = &aw;
                    game->Bypass();
                    game->Launch();
                    break;
            }

            lastID = XamGetCurrentTitleID();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see i could've moved the game->Launch() and game->Bypass() outside of the switch statement to have less code and only call it once, but i didn't knew how i could determine when a game needs a bypass and/or launch. This is my GameClass:

```
class Game
{
public:
    virtual void Bypass() { }

    virtual void Launch() { }
};
```

And this is the class of an example game:

```
// needs bypass and launch called
class AW : public Game
{
public:
    void Bypass()
    {
        // bypass
    }

    void Launch()
    {
        Sleep(500);
        XNotifyUI(L"AW - Loaded!");
    }
};
```

I would like to know if there is a way to do something like this:

```
DWORD GameChecker()
{
    DWORD lastID = NULL;

    Game *game;

    for (;;)
    {
        if (XamGetCurrentTitleID() != lastID)
        {
            switch (XamGetCurrentTitleID())
            {
                case BOOT_UP:
                    // nothing
                    break;
                default:
                    game = &functionThatReturnsClassBasedOnGame(XamGetCurrentTitleID()); // I don't know how to code such an function
                    break;
            }

            if (game->needsBypass)
                game->Bypass();

            if (game->needsLaunch)
                game->Launch();

            lastID = XamGetCurrentTitleID();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks for your time.

Comment: typedefing that enum is pointless. You lost C compatibility when you provided a base. And C++ already recognizes a `foo` to be `enum foo`.

Comment: `_XBOX` this is not a valid identifier name. At any scope, a name beginning with an underscore followed by a capital is reserved for standard implementation.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to accomplish your example is like this:

```
const int NEEDS_BYPASS = 1;
const int NEEDS_LAUNCH = 2;

class Game
{
public:
    virtual ~Game() { }
    virtual int getFeatures() const { return 0; }
    virtual void Bypass() { }
    virtual void Launch() { }
};

class Game_Dashboard : public Game
{
public:
    int getFeatures() const { return NEEDS_LAUNCH; }
    void Launch() {
        Sleep(500);
        XNotifyUI(L"Dashboard - Loaded!");
    }
};

class Game_ModernWarfare2 : public Game
{
public:
    int getFeatures() const { return NEEDS_LAUNCH; }
    void Launch() {
        Sleep(500);
        XNotifyUI(L"MW2 - Loaded!");
    }
};

class Game_ModernWarfare3 : public Game
{
public:
    int getFeatures() const { return NEEDS_LAUNCH; }
    void Launch() {
        Sleep(500);
        XNotifyUI(L"MW3 - Loaded!");
    }
};

class Game_Ghosts : public Game
{
public:
    int getFeatures() const { return NEEDS_BYPASS | NEEDS_LAUNCH; }
    void Bypass() {
        // bypass...
    }
    void Launch() {
        Sleep(500);
        XNotifyUI(L"Ghosts - Loaded!");
    }
};

class Game_BlackOpts1 : public Game
{
public:
    int getFeatures() const { return NEEDS_LAUNCH; }
    void Launch() {
        Sleep(500);
        XNotifyUI(L"BO1 - Loaded!");
    }
};

class Game_BlackOpts2 : public Game
{
public:
    int getFeatures() const { return NEEDS_BYPASS; }
    void Bypass() {
        // bypass...
    }
};

class Game_BlackOpts3 : public Game
{
public:
    int getFeatures() const { return NEEDS_BYPASS; }
    void Bypass() {
        // bypass...
    }
};

class Game_AdvancedWarfare : public Game
{
public:
    int getFeatures() const { return NEEDS_BYPASS | NEEDS_LAUNCH; }
    void Bypass() {
        // bypass
    }
    void Launch() {
        Sleep(500);
        XNotifyUI(L"AW - Loaded!");
    }
};

Game* getGame(DWORD ID)
{
    switch (ID)
    {
    case DASHBOARD:
        return new Game_Dashboard;
    case COD_MODERN_WARFARE_2:
        return new Game_ModernWarfare2;
    case COD_MODERN_WARFARE_3:
        return new Game_ModernWarfare3;
    case COD_GHOSTS:
        return new Game_Ghosts;
    case COD_BLACK_OPS_1:
        return new Game_BlackOpts1;
    case COD_BLACK_OPS_2:
        return new Game_BlackOpts2;
    case COD_BLACK_OPS_3:
        return new Game_BlackOpts3;
    case COD_ADVANCED_WARFARE:
        return new Game_AdvancedWarfare;
    }
    return NULL;
}

DWORD GameChecker()
{
    DWORD currentID, lastID = 0;
    Game *game;

    do
    {
        currentID = XamGetCurrentTitleID();
        if (currentID != lastID)
        {
            lastID = currentID;

            game = getGame(currentID);
            if  (game)
            {
                if (game->getFeatures() & NEEDS_BYPASS)
                    game->Bypass();

                if (game->getFeatures() & NEEDS_LAUNCH)
                    game->Launch();

                delete game;
            }
        }
    }
    while (true);

    return 0;
}
```

However, a better use of polymorphism would to be more like this instead:

```
class Game
{
public:
    virtual ~Game() { }
};

class CanBypass
{
public:
    virtual void Bypass() = 0;
};

class CanLaunch
{
public:
    virtual void Launch() = 0;
};

class Game_Dashboard : public Game, public CanLaunch
{
public:
    void Launch() {
        Sleep(500);
        XNotifyUI(L"Dashboard - Loaded!");
    }
};

class Game_ModernWarfare2 : public Game, public CanLaunch
{
public:
    void Launch() {
        Sleep(500);
        XNotifyUI(L"MW2 - Loaded!");
    }
};

class Game_ModernWarfare3 : public Game, public CanLaunch
{
public:
    void Launch() {
        Sleep(500);
        XNotifyUI(L"MW3 - Loaded!");
    }
};

class Game_Ghosts : public Game, public CanBypass, public CanLaunch
{
public:
    void Bypass() {
        // bypass...
    }
    void Launch() {
        Sleep(500);
        XNotifyUI(L"Ghosts - Loaded!");
    }
};

class Game_BlackOpts1 : public Game, public CanLaunch
{
public:
    void Launch() {
        Sleep(500);
        XNotifyUI(L"BO1 - Loaded!");
    }
};

class Game_BlackOpts2 : public Game, public CanBypass
{
public:
    void Bypass() {
        // bypass...
    }
};

class Game_BlackOpts3 : public Game, public CanBypass
{
public:
    void Bypass() {
        // bypass...
    }
};

class Game_AdvancedWarfare : public Game, public CanBypass, public CanLaunch
{
public:
    void Bypass() {
        // bypass
    }
    void Launch() {
        Sleep(500);
        XNotifyUI(L"AW - Loaded!");
    }
};

Game* getGame(DWORD ID)
{
    switch (ID)
    {
    case DASHBOARD:
        return new Game_Dashboard;
    case COD_MODERN_WARFARE_2:
        return new Game_ModernWarfare2;
    case COD_MODERN_WARFARE_3:
        return new Game_ModernWarfare3;
    case COD_GHOSTS:
        return new Game_Ghosts;
    case COD_BLACK_OPS_1:
        return new Game_BlackOpts1;
    case COD_BLACK_OPS_2:
        return new Game_BlackOpts2;
    case COD_BLACK_OPS_3:
        return new Game_BlackOpts3;
    case COD_ADVANCED_WARFARE:
        return new Game_AdvancedWarfare;
    }
    return NULL;
}

DWORD GameChecker()
{
    DWORD currentID, lastID = 0;
    Game *game;
    CanBypass *bypasser; 
    CanLaunch *launcher;

    do
    {
        currentID = XamGetCurrentTitleID();
        if (currentID != lastID)
        {
            lastID = currentID;

            game = getGame(currentID);
            if  (game)
            {
                bypasser = dynamic_cast<CanBypass*>(game);
                if (bypasser)
                    bypasser->Bypass();

                launcher = dynamic_cast<CanLaunch*>(game);
                if (launcher)
                    launcher->Launch();

                delete game;
            }
        }
    }
    while (true);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZgdDLHBW it throws a fatal exception (when i'm at the dashboard) after printing "Setting Bypasser / Launcher ...", so i guess the cast or something right here is wrong: bypasser = dynamic_cast<CanBypass*>(game);

Comment: could you please check the code you provided? it's not working :(

Comment: @ZZ_James: the code I gave you works fine as-is, I tested it. If it is crashing for you, then you have not incorporated it into your project correctly, but you didn't show all of your code, only your checker loop. And BTW, your loop is leaking memory since you commented out the `delete game;` statement. And why are you using `currentID = XamGetCurrentTitleID() != 0 ? XamGetCurrentTitleID() : 0;` instead of `currentID = XamGetCurrentTitleID();`? Your use of `?:` is redundant.